# Perl oneliner in bash: print matches from complex regexp

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I have this complex regex

```
/"_outV":([0-9]+),"_inV":([0-9]+),"_label":"([a-z\/]+)",/
```

and I need to parse a file (which is all on one single line) and output only the matched groups like

```
print $1 $2 $3
```

Currently the only *almost working* onliner is

```
perl -pe 'while(m/"_outV":([0-9]+)\,"_inV":([0-9]+)\,"_label":"([a-z\/]+)\"\,/g){print "$1 $2 $3\n";}'
```

But it ends up echoing also the entire file at the end, after the matches.
How do I fix this?

I though that removing the `-p` option would make the trick, but it doesn't.

Comment: Some example data would help. This looks like you have something to parse, and you're trying to regex hack it, which is probably the wrong way to tackle it.

Comment: I began to write an answer, but I must go now. My intent was to say that you shouldn't strive for a one-line program in any language. Two levels of escaping make everything horribly difficult to debug. Unless you have a good reason to need a one-line command, and I can't think of a valid one, then it is much better written as a Perl program in a separate file. Anything beyond a trivial regex pattern should almake use of the options of changing the delimiter and using the `/x` modifier. Complex one-liners are for young programmers who like to play "tricks"; they are not for professional use,

Comment: @Borodin This is hardly complex.

Comment: @123: Complexity is relative. The OP says *"I have this complex regex"*, so to them it is complex, and to say otherwise would be churlish.

Comment: @Borodin You said complex one-liner,which this isn't as it is a single loop. The regex will be complex(depending on user) regardless of whether it is in a full script or not.

Comment: @123: This is a little silly. Are you one of the "young programmers" that I wrote about? The most trivial regex pattern can be awkward to escape properly as a "one-liner", and this is a "complex" one. I think that makes the one-liner complex too. The bottom line is that, if the OP hadn't been trying to cram everything into a single bash command then they would have had much less trouble. There is an unprofitable culture of trying to "golf" code into unmaintainable bash commands, and it's something you should do in your spare time, not at your employer's expense.

Comment: @Kuzeko: I think you're processing JSON data, and you would be much better off using the `JSON` module to process it rather than misusing regular expressions.

Comment: @Borodin Sure, if not completely disregarding one-liners for trivial problems makes me a `young programmer` .I definitely disagree that the "most trivial" regex patterns are difficult to escape, the only problematic part would be using single quotes, which OP is not. The bottom line is that the only problem OP had was that they didn't check what the flags they were using did, so i doubt they would have an easier time reading and writing from file manually. Writing one-liners doesn't automatically make them unreadable... It's also unprofitable to over complicate simple one-off scripts.

Comment: @123: Straw man much? I disagree.

Comment: @Borodin Great argument, what part is a straw man? I literally replied to only your points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me.
You need to *replace* the `-p` with `-n` and [here is why](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node164.html).

A few finer points:

- No need to backslash those `,` and `"`.
- You can conveniently replace`[0-9]` with `\d`.
- By using a different delimiter for the regex you won't need to escape the `/`.

End result optimized

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 $2 $3\n" while m{"_outV":(\d+),"_inV":(\d+),"_label":"([a-z/]+)",}g'
```

Comment: Awesome, and the optimization it's even better!

Comment: The obligatory proviso is that `\d` and `[0-9]` are not equivalent unless the `/a` modifier is in place

Comment: @Borodin Hah! I didn't know about `/a` :) Another chunk to read. Why anyone ever listens to me I'll never know.